# Django "OR" like statement in Queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Just have a simple syntax question onto Django,
imagining the following queryset:

```
queryset = Requests.objects.get_queryset().filter(
    status='Pending',
    up_rank__gte=config.REQ_RANK - 10,
    down_rank__gte=config.REQ_RANK - 10
)
```

Is there any way that I can setup my query like that:

> up_vote__gte=config.REQ_RANK - 10 OR down_vote__gte=config.REQ_RANK -
> 10 ?! (See pseudo OR)

As I want to filter onto both, up_rank and down_rank __gte. The only way I know would be a query chain but to me that seems not to be efficient, Is there any other way than a query chain statement or do I just talk nonsense and chain is fine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can wrap the conditions in [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q), and make use of the bitwise or operator (`|`), this will make a `Q` object that is the disjunction:

```
from django.db.models import Q

queryset = Requests.objects.get_queryset().filter(
    Q(up_rank__gte=config.REQ_RANK - 10) |
    Q(down_rank__gte=config.REQ_RANK - 10),
    status='Pending'
)
```